# Canny:cv2.imshow('Canny',img) what does " : " mean in python ? , Countours = [] what does "[]" mean in python?

Tags: python

Canny:cv2.imshow('Canny',img) what does " : " mean in python ?
Countours = [] what does "[]" mean in python ?

Comment: `Canny:cv2` doesn't mean *anything*; it's a syntax error. Where did you see this? As for `[]`,that's covered early in any remotely decent tutorial.

Comment: Actually, `Canny: cv2.imshow('Canny', img)` is a valid variable annotation, though I would not expect to see a method call used as an annotation like this.

Answer (score 0):

Some code editors will show [ ] (empty list) as [], which may be confusing.
As for the ":", I don't think this is valid syntax.  When I worked with OpenCV, I did:

```py
import cv2
...
...
cv2.imshow("My image", my_image_mat)
```

In the future, when asking questions, please include as much useful information as possible.  Where did you see this code?  What are you trying to do with it?  Where is the rest?

Also, [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) is a tutorial I once followed on Canny.  A sample from it:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
edges = cv.Canny(img,100,200)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Also, as per the `contours = []`, Python supports named keyword arguments to functions, in other words, a function can take a number of arguments with default values and a name, see this [link](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-keyword-arguments-in-python).

Comment: The colon is *not* valid syntax, which is why I asked the OP where they saw it.